# For loop position in csv reader_Python

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

In this piece of my script when max_conc is calculated, the next for loop doesn't work unless I put it right after the reader. But doing so, max_conc doesn't work anymore.

```
with open ('outfile.csv', 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)

    max_conc = max(cols[1] for cols in reader)
    print max_conc

    for row in reader:
    print row
```

Is reopening the input file the only solution?

Comment: Try adding `rows = list(reader)` and then using `rows` instead of `reader`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you called:

```
max(cols[1] for cols in reader)
```

You exhausted the iterator, you can't loop through it again. But you can use `seek` to get back to the beginning of the file:

```
infile.seek(0)
```

Or, you can store a copy of the file in the memory:

```
lines = infile.readlines()
max_conc = max(cols[1] for cols in lines)
```

Another way, as @Lyncha suggested, loop through a list-copy of the file:

```
lines = list(reader)
```

Here's a little example:

```
>>> f = open('test.txt')
>>> f.read()
'a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\ng'
>>> f.read()
''  #whoops, iterator is exhausted
>>> f.seek(0)
>>> f.read()
'a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\ng'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just when added lines = infile.readlines() I should use lines instead of reader from then on. right?

Comment: Would you edit answer to reflect it please. This didn't work: lines = infile.readlines()
max_conc = max(cols[1] for cols in reader)

Comment: change `for cols in reader` to `for cols in line.split(',') for line in lines`. You need to split it in the commas, am i correct?

Comment: An easier way would be to copy and store it in a list; `list(reader)`.

Comment: just changing it to lines works. Didn't know reader is a disposable item! :) thanks